# How to disable and enable USB device in Windows 10 without reboot

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

I am trying to solve some problem that arises from having a FTDI USB2serial adapter feeding power into a MCU while the MCU is not powered itself.

If I unplug the USB serial device, everything is fine.

Unfortunately everything should run in an automated environment lateron, which is why I need to simulate unplugging the device with some command line tool in Windows 10.

Disabling the USB device in Device manager requires reboot which is a no-go.

I found some questions where answers suggested using these tools:

- [DevCon](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon): The page suggests not to use it anymore but use this instead:
- [PnpUtil](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil): This seems to require the same reboot that I already saw with manually disabling the device in DeviceManager.
- [comdisable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/8485f553-11b6-c663-2f19-f2702494602f): Unfortunately this seems to be available only for historic version of Windows.

Is there another way to disable a device?
Or maybe there is another way to stop the USB port to deliver power to the USB-serial adapter apart from disabling the device?

Comment: Have you found any solution? I also tried `devcon` to no avail, it still required a reboot for me, as per [my comment on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47530182/enabling-disabling-a-device-in-windows-10-from-command-line/63219662#comment132810352_59490940).

Comment: No, I did not find a suitable solution. We found some way to disconnect the pins on the device side.

Comment: Just leaving here for information that [I found an alternative that suited my needs](https://superuser.com/a/1765710/327009).

Comment: Is this an option for you: https://www.yepkit.com/product/300115/YKUSHXS

Comment: @JoepvanSteen nice gadget. That would be an option but in the meantime we added some BeagleBone board to our setup to connect/disconnect the wires

Answer (score 1):

Although Microsoft prefers that you use PnpUtil, Devcon still works
and is simpler to use.

A standalone version is available from Github at
[DevCon-Installer](https://github.com/Drawbackz/DevCon-Installer).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "simpler to use". `pnputil /enum-devices /connected /class Ports` and `pnputil /disable-device FTDIBUS\VID_0403+PID_6001+00000000A\0000` is already very simple. Unfortunately the device is only marked as disabled in DeviceManager but the FTDI is still powered.

Comment: To each his own taste. Now, about USB power-off: Windows is not very good on powering down ejected/disabled devices. Try this [registry edit](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/usb-port-remains-active-even-after-using-safely-remove-hardware) (although I don't know if it's still working in Windows 10).

Comment: [For my device, `devcon` still requires a reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47530182/enabling-disabling-a-device-in-windows-10-from-command-line/63219662#comment132810352_59490940) which is a no-go for me. Would you know why is that, or any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

[For my device, both `devcon` and `pnputil` were requiring a reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47530182/enabling-disabling-a-device-in-windows-10-from-command-line/63219662#comment132810352_59490940), which was a no-go for me.

The only program that allowed me to disable/enable my device via command line without reboot was a third-party app, [*DevManView*](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/device_manager_view.html). This can also be invoked via command line, and I was able to incorporate it in a `.bat` file and invoke it upon certain events to automatically enable/disable the device, as I needed. A life saver.